# SQL query to sort

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have table products and table seen. Every time a customer views a product an entry is added for that product in seen table. I want to retrieve list of all products from products table and sort the list of products in desc order of how many times its been viewed.Note if a product hasn't been viewed even once then there will be no entry in seen table, and that product should be put at top of the list followed by products which have been viewed once,twice and so on

```
SELECT products.product_id ,products.product_name , anon_1.seen_count
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT seen.product_id , count(*) AS seen_count
     FROM seen 
     GROUP BY seen.product_id
     ) AS anon_1 ON anon_1.product_id = products.product_id  
ORDER BY anon_1.seen_count ASC;
```

My above query puts the products that haven't been viewed at the bottom. How do i fix this?
I have tried both descending and ascending. Descending puts the ones that have been least viewed at the bottom and ascending puts the ones that have not been viewed at the bottom

Comment: You can't have "list of products in **desc** order of how many times its been viewed" and " that product should be put at top of the list followed by products which have been viewed **once,twice and so on**" at the same time

Comment: `... ORDER BY anon_1.seen_count NULLS FIRST` [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html)

Comment: MySQL (probably) or Postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you should consider **NULL** value for `products that haven't been viewed`. So you should use this:

```
SELECT products.product_id ,products.product_name, 
    COALESCE(anon_1.seen_count, 0) seen_count
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT seen.product_id , count(*) AS seen_count
     FROM seen 
     GROUP BY seen.product_id
     ) AS anon_1 ON anon_1.product_id = products.product_id  
ORDER BY seen_count ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ORDER BY anon_1.seen_count DESC;
>   it sorts them from the greatest value to smallest.

You should use

```
 ORDER BY anon_1.seen_count ASC;
```

to sort from the smallest to greatest.

Comment: Sorry actually I have tried both descending and ascending. Descending puts the ones that have been least viewed at the bottom and ascending puts the ones that have not been viewed at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT products.product_id ,products.product_name , CASE WHEN anon_1.seen_count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE anon_1.seen_count END AS count
FROM products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT seen.product_id , count(*) AS seen_count
     FROM seen 
     GROUP BY seen.product_id
     ) AS anon_1 ON anon_1.product_id = products.product_id  
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Comment: Hmmm... this will result in non seen products being at the bottom by virtue of the `ORDER BY count DESC`, i.e. it will go from greatest to smallest value. If you want non seen products at the top, i.e. smallest to greatest value use `ORDER BY count ASC`.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql and SqlServer, null value is the min value. But for Oracle, null value is the max value. 
So you might using MySql or SqlServer, right?
Current result would be as follow, we need to put the last one to the top, which seen_count is null.
[image]

In order to do this, I add an additional column to solve it. Does that meet with your need? Hope that could help you!

[image]